# Display tooltip/message while input is invalid HTML/JS/CSS/Angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have an HTML input field where certain characters shouldn't be allowed. The functional part is solved, but I would like to display a tooltip/message next to the input field **while** it contains illegal characters.

I have a boolean which keeps track of this, but I've been unable to make a satisfactory tooltip/message.

I've tried tweaking uib-tooltip, but It requires the user to hover over the input area. I've tried making a span/div/label that's hidden/displayed based on the boolean, but my CSS skills aren't strong enough.

The app uses Angularjs and Bootstrap 3.

The input field is not part of a form.

Comment: You can manually set the visibility of the `uib-tooltip` using the `tooltip-is-open` attribute. Simply use the same boolean you are using to keep track of the invalid characters.

Comment: Thanks, worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This comment by user [Lex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/548997/lex) solved the problem.

> You can manually set the visibility of the uib-tooltip using the
>   tooltip-is-open attribute. Simply use the same boolean you are using
>   to keep track of the invalid characters.

Answer (score 0):

where you catch that boolean just say to display the div next to input like

```
myDiv.visible = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your exact Javascript, I can't really answer it directly.

I would do something like

```
function invalid() {
  if (invalid = true) {
    document.getElementById("alert").style.visibility = 'visible'
  }
}
```

make sure the error message is set to hidden,

then have the checker function run on focus..

```
<input type="text" onfocus="invalid()">
```

https://jsfiddle.net/we67geke/1/

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned

> The app uses Angularjs and Bootstrap 3.

I suggest that you should use Boostrap tooltip. Use `$('#element').tooltip('show')` and `$('#element').tooltip('hide')` with your flag to handle status of Tooltip.

I don't know how your codes work, my idea seems like:

**HTML:**

`<input type=text (keypress)="eventHandler()"> // angular >= 2`

`<input type=text ng-keypress="eventHandler()"> // angular 1`

**Angular code:**

```
eventHandler() {
  if (isIllegal) {
    $('#element').tooltip('show');
  } else {
    $('#element').tooltip('hide');
  }
}
```

Something like that.

**Bootstrap Tooltip:** https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#tooltips